# Upgrade path SQL Server 2008 RTM 32 to SQL Server 2016 Standard

Tags: sql-server

I do not have much SQL experience and I'm trying to help a client out. They are currently utilizing SQL Server 2008 RTM 32-bit on Windows Server 2012. I am attempting to get them to SQL Server 2016 Standard. I know you cannot traditionally upgrade 32 to 64-bit platform.

Would the best plan of action be to:

1. Backup all of the databases on the instance
2. Drop\detach All active databases
3. Uninstall SQL Server 2008 RTM (named instance)
4. Reboot
5. Install SQL Server 2016 with same instance name
6. Restore all of the SQL Server 2008 32-bit databases to the new instance

Comment: It's harder than a simple backup + restore. Don't drop/detach/uninstall 2008 until you know that your migration works. They need to keep their database intact and accessible while you practice. Clone the server into a VM. Practice on the VM until it all works. Then you're ready to do it in the real environment. You will have to drop/recreate the database users in the restored dbs. You will also need to see if they use things like CLR, FILESTREAM, and other 2008 technologies, and setup those up correctly in 2016, AND TEST EVERYTHING. Some code may need to be rewritten. Take it slow, be careful.

Comment: Another thought.  The licensing for SQL Server 2008 is a lot different than 2016.  Are they prepared for the cost difference?

Comment: Is an OS upgrade needed as well? And run the upgrade advisor to find potential feature / code problems. And some form of testing for applications is needed BEFORE the upgrade to the production system.